# Suspend and resume X session?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, x

I use [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen) for terminal multiplexing, and I was wondering if a similar solution existed for desktop environments. This is not the same concept as locking the screen, or logging out of the desktop. But to truly suspend, and then resume the [X server](https://www.x.org) at a later time without loss of data.

Also, I am not using Gnome or KDE, neither am I using a login manager.

**Desired Behaviour**

1) Login via the console.

2) Run `startx`.

3) Launch Firefox, Terminal, etc.

4) Suspend current X session; user is returned back to the console.

5) Resume previous X session; user is returned back to desktop environment.

Note: all previously running applications should still be present.

**Research**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is used to suspend a job in the terminal.
This is used in conjunction with `fg` to resume the process.

The `kill` command can also send signals to a running process, e.g. -STOP, -CONT, among others.

Comment: I would also like some functionality like this. Does connecting to another tty satisfy you? Pressing Ctrl-Alt-F2 should provide you with a second login console, in which you can do whatever you like. If it is important to you that the X server running on tty1 is really paused, you can pause it with `killall -TSTP X` or similar, and resume it with `killall -CONT X`. Similarly you can just pause your window manager if you prefer.

Comment: A warning: Do not switch back to tty1 while the X server is paused. I don't know exactly why, but this freezes my console. My guess is that X is still set up to swallow all input, but can't process it because the process is paused. If you pause and then continue, though, I experienced no problems. However, if it is important to you that you are attached to tty1, I don't know how to do that! If not, I can turn these comments into an answer.

Comment: I know I can switch to another TTY, but I would really like to be able to suspend the graphical session.

Comment: Does suspending the graphical session from another terminal not work for you either? (I appreciate that the ideal is some functionality similar to ctrl-z, but I'm not sure how to get that).

Comment: You may find this discussion helpful: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8505598.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [xpra](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/blob/master/README.md) is a solution for you? It works like screen for X connections.